# Getting value from groupby matrix

Tags: python, pandas, validation, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I currently have a dataset that looks like this.

```
DateTime, CustomerID, 2, 3, Product Subclass, ProductID, 6, 7, 8
2001-01-08 00:00:00;01217544  ;E ;E ;530112;4710094020568;1;51;66
2001-01-08 00:00:00;00102292  ;D ;F ;560102;4710032502811;1;115;128
2001-01-08 00:00:00;01443141  ;C ;E ;500538;2250078000251;1;69;78
2001-01-08 00:00:00;01439274  ;J ;E ;100401;4710043001211;1;409;450
2001-01-08 00:00:00;01724790  ;D ;F ;100202;4710047512065;1;15;18
2001-01-08 00:00:00;02013275  ;J ;E ;110217;4710892632017;2;370;398
```

I have split this data into smaller matrices, one matrix per date and customer. I would like to extract the productID from each of those matrices and create a transactional dataset for each day per customer, with rows of productID's for each transaction.

However, I am currently stuck on getting the productID from my smaller matrices. I am able to split the data with the groupby function. However, this yields 1x1 blocks with text where I can't seem to retrieve the ProductID from. How can I get the ProductID from my created groups so that I can put them together in one column, in a new array?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

'''DateTime, CustomerID, Product Subclass, ProductID'''
D01 = pd.read_csv('Data/D01.txt', sep=';', header=0, names=['DateTime','CustomerID','ProductSubclass', 'ProductID'], usecols=(0,1,4,5))
groupedData = np.asmatrix(D01.groupby(['DateTime','CustomerID']))

print np.asmatrix(groupedData)
```

My current output for one transaction

```
[('2001-01-31 00:00:00', 2174006)
                     DateTime  CustomerID  ProductSubclass      ProductID
214244  2001-01-31 00:00:00     2174006           100208  4710144202227
214468  2001-01-31 00:00:00     2174006           500111  4718433614799
214819  2001-01-31 00:00:00     2174006           100110  4901550332077
215420  2001-01-31 00:00:00     2174006           500303  4710367807421]]
```

Desired output

```
 ...   
(4710144202227, 4718433614799, 4901550332077, 4710367807421)
 ...
```

Comment: Why are you using `np.asmatrix()` twice on the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
# make data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'datetime' : [pd.to_datetime('2001-01-08')] * 6,
    'customerID' : ['01217544', '00102292', '01443141', '01439274', '01724790', '02013275'],
    2 : ['E', 'D', 'C', 'J', 'D', 'D'],
    3 : ['E', 'F', 'E', 'E', 'F', 'E'],
    'product_subclass' : [530112, 560102, 500538, 100401, 100202, 110217],
    'productID' : [4710094020568, 4710032502811, 2250078000251, 4710043001211, 4710047512065, 4710892632017],
    6 : [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
    7 : [51, 115, 69, 409, 15, 370],
    8 : [66, 128, 78, 450, 18, 398]
})

# set index as 'datetime' and 'customerID'
df = df.set_index([
    'datetime',
    'customerID'
]).sort_index()

# cross section on 2001-01-08 and customerID = 00102292
df.xs(['20010108', '00102292'])['productID']
```

[image: output]

Comment: Not exactly, however your indexing solution has helped me understand DataFrames a little better! All I needed was np.asmatrix(groupedData.item(1))[1,3]